# Receive Error when trying to load flextable library

Tags: flextable

After loading the flextable library, I am receiving the following error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘flextable’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/systemfonts/libs/systemfonts.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/systemfonts/libs/systemfonts.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/systemfonts/libs/systemfonts.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The following instructions should help: https://github.com/davidgohel/gdtools#for-mac-os-users?